# Building NDK app with Android ADT on Windows

Tags: android, c++, windows, android-ndk, adt

While there are tons of information on the topic, there is no clear guide on how to compile C++ code in ADT.
Is Cygwin is required? 
Where the build artifacts go? How to confogure the destination folder for the build package? Are there a debug and release versions? Is it possible to debug and step through the C++ code in ADT?
Maybe it all is described in a single resource, then a link would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that on Windows, you have a completely different option to integrate Android development with Visual Studio 2010: http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/.

There is a solution for visual debugging, Visual Studio style: http://visualgdb.com/?features=android (but this is not free).

There seems to be another option, as well: http://www.wingdb.com/wgMobileEdition.htm, which works with VS 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Just download the brand new ADT bundle at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and NDK  r8c at http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html. You don't need cygwin, your NDK build is fully integrated with normal Android development (i.e. the binaries are copied to the `lib/armeabi` folder and automatically picked up by the APK builder).

It is possible to debug native code (if your app is debuggable), and you can choose release or debug configuration for your native code by running

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1      --> force a debuggable build
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0      --> force a release build
```

I strongly recommend that you read the NDK documentation and play with the samples provided as part of the NDK before you start doing things on your own. Actually NDK build system is a wrapper around GNU make, and it is very easy to make the things very complicated by misusing these tools.

Comment: I am looking for a way to avoid using command line to build NDK code.

Comment: You can avoid command line for build and debug. You still need command line to investigate crash log.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your guide. I have seen this comment at other places as well that we don't need cygwin, but with the latest NDK here: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html, it specifically says in the requirement that cygwin is required. Is it that they started to have this requirement again or it's still not required? (I'm trying cygwin with a lot of errors)

Comment: @PiyushSoni: the NDK doc is sometimes misleading. One thing that they emphasize is that the older versions of cygwin will not work. There are some concealed dependencies on cygwin even in current r9d. For example, you need bash to debug C code. Eclipse adds its share to confusion: when you load a project with native support on a machine with no cygwin, there is a warning about cygdrive missing. But after load, it works fine. Curiously, through Eclipse you can debug native code without cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a page that is a lot of help http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin
I will probably add more information here later to help others on the topic.